# Woocommerce: Deactivate ajax on cart page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

Somehow Ajax product removal is not working on my site. If i click on the remove icon then Ajax scrolls on page but no product is removed from cart. The only way to remove product from cart is manually change quantity to zero. See short screencast video https://www.screencast.com/t/qLv8z3gw

I deactivated all plugins except Woocommerce but no luck. Also tried with three different themes (Twenty seventeen along them) but the issue is still there.

Is there a way do deactivate Ajax on cart page and make page somehow manually refresh and remove product after clicking on Remove icon?

Thanks

Comment: Also, it seems that:
1. If i refresh page manually then those products are removed
2. It seems to be happening only for logged in users

Comment: You should add a live link to your website, as this seems like a javascript error issue. Also you should check your configuration in WooCommerce > Status (looking for red alerts). The best way to see if you have javascript errors is to inspect the cart page with your browser Developer tool looking at the console (for errors)…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it was hosting server related issue. If i switched servers then everything was normal again.